# Undesired character appearing when I hover over Glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Glyphicon in an `echo` statement:

```
<a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id=";?><?php echo $thought_id;?><?php echo "'>
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' aria-hidden='true' style='padding-right: 5px;'></span> 
</a>
```

When I am not hovering over the icon, the icon dislays fine, but when I hover over the icon, an underscore character appears, as shown in the image below:

[image]

As you can see, that annoying `_` appears besides the `|` when I hover over the icon.

I have no CSS defined to change the properties of the icon on hover. I have simply added the glyphicon into HTML. Having said that, I am using bootstrap (which may be why the icon changes color when I hover over it).

I just want to remove the annoying character, but I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: At a guess: `a:hover { text-decoration: none; }` . Difficult to say without an example

Comment: Get rid of the white space in your code.

Comment: @j08691 - Hi. Thanks for your comment. I have removed the white space but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Turnip - Hi. I have tried to apply that CSS. It unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Can you create a stack snippet, jsFiddle, bootply, etc. example with the HTML (not PHP) showing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code looks a bit strange:

```
<a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id=";?><?php echo $thought_id;?><?php echo "'>
```

You are mixing single and double quotes, the last php tag isn't closed (with "?>"), the question mark before the closing bracket aof the `<a>` tag?

Could it be that it should be like this?:

```
<a href='/inc/favourite_post.php?id='><?php echo $thought_id;?><?php echo '';?>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have tried it the way you mentioned, but it doesn't seem to work. My assumption is that the `_` must be echo'd somewhere for it to be appearing, but I cant' find such an echo.

Comment: you could examine it in the browser's devoloper tool: If it is a separate element with its own class or ID (or can otherwise be addressed separately by combined CSS selectors), you could either hide it via CSS (display: none; ) or in case it has text-decoration: underline, eliminate that with a CSS rule "text-decoration: none;". And anyway, that second PHP echo in your code is still strange - try to leave it out.